# WebKit WKWebView attempts to make service calls to Apple when using local URL

Tags: xcode, macos, swift3, webkit, wkwebview

I'm using Webkit WKWebView to display locally stored HTML files in my OSX application for specific formatted pages.

Each of the WebView objects is linked to a WKWebview object in the storyboard of the application and is initialized using:

```
    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView! = WKWebView()
```

I then display a local HTML using WebView:

```
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "termsandconditions", withExtension: "html")
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(url: url!)
    outputView.load(urlRequest as URLRequest)
```

For each of the Webview Objects defined, XCode returns a warning

> Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service

Am I initializing the WebViews correctly? Why is it trying to connect to the Apple service if I'm only using a local URL?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet, but will update if I get it resolved. Seems like you can submit your app to the App Store but still bugs me as "unclean" code, so will keep hacking away at it.

Answer (score 0):

Determined that this is an Xcode issue making a call to the Apple. When compiled and running on a different device I cannot pick up the call being made.

Comment: Found another method to remove these updated. Set up a new environment attribute "OS_ACTIVITY_MODE" and make it "disabled". This will remove any OS sourced updates from the console in XCode.